# Querying nodes with multiple relationships (outgoing and incoming)

Tags: neo4j

I have relationship called `KNOWS` as shown below. How to return details of both incoming and outgoing relationship and properties inside the relationship such as "from" "month".

```
a-[:knows{from:1992, month:december}]->b
b-[:knows{from:1993, month:april}]->a
a-[:knows{from:1994, month:agust}]->c
```

I want to query something like:

```
MATCH (n:person{name:'a'})-[:KNOWS]->(person) OR (person)-[:KNOWS]-> n:person{name:'a'})
RETURN person.name, from, month 


MATCH (n:person{name:'a'})-[:KNOWS]->(person)
```

The above query will just return `b` and `c`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get both incoming and outgoing relationships, just omit the directional arrow, and to get the properties from the relationship, you'll need to add a variable on the relationship in the match:

```
MATCH (:person{name:'a'})-[r:KNOWS]-(person)
RETURN person.name, r.from, r.month
```